# Jquery event handler works only with anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I have some jQuery that changes a bit of text when a button is clicked. This code works fine when implemented within an anonymous function (`nn_list` is a globally defined array of strings, `nn_flag` predefined as false):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nn_button").click(function(){
        $('.nickname').empty();

        var random_name = nn_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * nn_list.length)];
        console.log(random_name);
        $('.nickname').append("<p>" + random_name + "</p>");
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work (doesn't change the text) when I implement it as a non-anonymous function:

```
var main = function(){
    $("#nn_button").click(function(){
        $('.nickname').empty();

        var random_name = nn_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * nn_list.length)];
        console.log(random_name);
        $('.nickname').append("<p>" + random_name + "</p>");
    });
}
$(document).ready(main());
```

Can someone explain to me what changes between those two implementations that makes the anonymous function work, but not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the function, not call it:

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass it, don't invoke it. Observe the following....

```
$(document).ready(main());
```

=>

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: *facepalm* Makes perfect sense, once I think about it. Thanks for quick answer.